# Error starting tunnel Starting tunnels timed out

Tags: react-native, expo, ngrok

I am using expo to start a react-native project and trying to use expo tunnel to able to work on the company network. However, I can't figure the error every time I start the tunnel and got the error " Error starting tunnel Starting tunnels timed out". I have tried reinstall expo-cli, node, and install ngrok. still not working. Please help!!!!!!!

Expo CLI 4.1.6 environment info:
System:
OS: macOS 11.2.1
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.15.5 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 7.5.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 14.4, DriverKit 20.2, macOS 11.1, tvOS 14.3, watchOS 7.2
IDEs:
Xcode: 12.4/12D4e - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
expo: ~40.0.0 => 40.0.1
react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz => 0.63.2
react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18
Expo Workflow: managed

[expo error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqHRH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your company network may be blocking the ngrok agent from connecting and setting up its session. Some of the following may reveal what's going on.

Try performing a DNS lookup of records associated with the ngrok agent session setup domain:

`dig tunnel.us.ngrok.com`

If DNS resolution succeeds, try making an HTTP request to the ngrok agent session setup domain, and inspect the output for connectivity issues:

`curl -kvI https://tunnel.us.ngrok.com`

If the network's policy requires you to use an outbound proxy for HTTP requests, there are configuration options for that within the ngrok config file: https://ngrok.com/docs#outbound-proxy

Alternatively you may need to ask a network administrator to explicitly allow outbound connections to the ngrok agent session setup domain or IP addresses.